# Where can I read the The Seven Deadly Sins manga online legally?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

So, I'm watching the anime *The Seven Deadly Sins* and I'd really love to read the manga, but I can't find it anywhere.

I even looked it up and only found one website, but it only published the recent chapters and deleted the older ones.

Where can I read it legally?

Comment: see here to see more complete list of legal site http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/923/2869

Answer (score 11):

*The Seven Deadly Sins* is part of Kodansha Comics, which have been made available on Crunchyroll since their manga platform release in 2013<sup>[1](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-10-26/crunchyroll-to-simultaneously-offer-kodansha-manga-in-170-countries),[2](http://www.nikkei.com/article/DGXNASFE2600M_W3A021C1MM8000/)</sup>. Crunchyroll has all the current chapters of this up to date. As of today, that is chapters 1-167.

You can read it on their website at:

http://www.crunchyroll.com/comics/manga/the-seven-deadly-sins/volumes

You'll need a Crunchyroll premium account to read all but the most recent simulpub release. You can use this [guest pass](http://www.crunchyroll.com/guest_pass?code=DNG5Z43H8BD) if you'd like a free 48 hour trial.

As stated on [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Deadly_Sins_(manga)) for *The Seven Deadly Sins* the availability is based on your locale:

> As the series is published in Japan, it is also released simultaneously in English digitally by Crunchyroll in over 170 countries.

You should be able to read it there without an issue unless you're in one of the few unsupported countries, e.g. Japan, China, France, Germany and Italy<sup>[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crunchyroll_Manga)</sup>.

Comment: Note: manga availability on the site may depend on where the OP is based

Comment: @Maroon thanks for pointing that out, there are a few countries that this manga is restricted from it seems. I've updated my answer.